# Regex which i wrote is generalizing markdown syntax between start and end pattern rather than being specific to single expression/word

Tags: regex, text

I have a sentence -

"She has breathing problems for so many years now. In `[\*\*2118-6-4\*\*]` she was admitted to `[\*\*Hospital1 18\*\*]` for respiratory failure due to a lung cancer. Due to persistent coughing, she was admitted... `[**Hospital1 **]...`

I wanted to identify and eliminate patterns enclosed between `[\*\*` and `\*\*]`

I wrote regex expressions as below -

```
\[\*\*\w*\s\*\*\]
```

Above expression identified the pattern - `[**Hospital1 **]`

I tried again and wrote the below-

```
\[\*\*\w*.*\*\*\]
```

This time it identified the whole strig - `[\*\*2118-6-4\*\*] she was admitted to [\*\*Hospital1 18\*\*]`

How should i modify my regex to be very specific for individual patterns between `[\*\*" and "\*\*]`

Comment: Reformat your question please, it's `markdown` syntax. Add two spaces after line endings, and make use of the buttons on the editor.

Comment: In your second regexp, `.*` is a "greedy" match. Try the non-greedy version: `.*?`

Comment: What is wrong with `[**Hospital1 **]`?

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps I am doing text processing and need to eliminate all the markdown syntax from the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `/\[\*\*[\s\d\w-]+\*\*\]/g`?

This will match zero or more word, digit, whitespace or hyphen characters in between `[**` and `**]`.

This can be seen working on Regex101 **[here](https://regex101.com/r/EyTssz/1/)**, and in JavaScript below:

```js
const string = "She has breathing problems for so many years now. In [**2118-6-4**] she was admitted to [**Hospital1 18**] for respiratory failure due to a lung cancer. Due to persistent coughing, she was admitted... [**Hospital1 **]...";
const regex = /\[\*\*[\w\d\s-]+\*\*\]/g;
console.log(string.match(regex));
```

Answer (score 0):

For your pattern, the RE is almost funny!  Try -

```
\[\*\*[^*]*\*\*\]
```

The `[^*]*` portion in the middle ensures that it grabs everything that is not an asterisk.  This should work (almost?) everywhere (it is a **Basic RE**).  If you are using a specific editor that supports look-ahead REs, then you can tweak it to look for everything until the two-asterisk followed by the `]`